# Difference between *splendid* and *splendiferous*

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I just read a post where someone was using the adjective *splendiferous* and even remarked he would not use that word lightly.

So I did a quick search and found that it has the same meaning as *splendid*, as well as the same function, i.e. both are adjectives.

**What is special about *splendiferous* in contrast to *splendid*?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=splendiferous):

> **splendiferous (adj.)**
>   considered a playful elaboration since its re-birth in 1843, but it was a perfectly good 15c. word, from Medieval Latin *splendorifer,* from *splendor* (see ***splendor***) + *ferre* "to bear" (see ***infer***).

Thus, it's a valid word with approximately the same meaning and usage as *splendid,* but it's now considered more fanciful than the simpler word, more appropriate for whimsical or ostentatious contexts.

Comment: How about supercalifragilisticexpialidocious?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that *splendiferous* is a 19th century coinage meant as an intensification of *splendid*, which is a couple of centuries older.

Since *splendid* is already a fairly intense word, *splendiferous* is usually a deliberately florid choice.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to use splendiferous these days without sounding silly and pretentious. You may find it used seriously in older books (say, 150 years ago or so).

In a very technical sense, "splendiferous" means "bringing or containing splendor" not merely being splendid. Similarly carboniferous means "containing carbon." So a "splendid city" would be a great place in its own right, but a "splendiferous city" would be one that contained multiple splendid things--even if the city itself were ugly. I cannot find any evidence that anyone has ever actually made this distinction, though.